# Installing MySQL on CentOS using shell script

Tags: linux, centos

I am writing a script where I should install MySQL on my Centos hard disk when I run it.
I downloaded the following :

> mysql-apt-config_0.8.5-1_all.deb

But I don't figure out how to install it from the shell script.

I am new to Linux and any help is appreciated !!

Comment: Note that .deb files are used in Debian-based distros.  CentOS uses RPMs, typically with yum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Centos is yum package manager just run the following commands to install MySql

If you are using Centos 7, you need to first add the repository as follows

```
wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
yum update
```

To install MySql on Centos, we run

```
sudo yum install mysql-server
sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

Note: `.deb` files are only used for Debian based Linux Distros. Centos uses `.rpm` files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save following command in a shell file(extension with .sh) and run with sudo.

```
#!/bin/bash**strong text**
export http_proxy= $Write proxy
export https_proxy= $ write proxy
sudo -E yum -y update
sudo -E yum -y install wget
wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
sudo  rpm -ivh mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
sudo -E yum -y update
sudo -E yum -y install mysql-server
sudo systemctl start mysqld
sleep 1s
mysql -u root <<-EOF
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('123') WHERE User='root';
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='root' AND Host NOT IN ('localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1');
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='';
DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db='test' OR Db='test_%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EOF
```